# Reading java code from a file and performing it

Tags: java

Let's say I have code inside a PLAIN TEXT FILE:

```
File f = new File("file.txt");
try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Is there a way I can perform that code, and if so, how? i.e. my application would have a method that would read the file, and actually do the code. Is there a way to do this?

The code inside the file is read by my application. I then want to execute this code as if it is a compiled java program.

Comment: You question is not clear. Please explain what do you meen "perform that code, "

Comment: perform is also same as execute. means doing something

Comment: could you further explain your question? it is not clear enough

Comment: I looked at the question that was linked, but it didn't have anything that answered my question. That's why I asked something similar here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What code is contained in the file.txt? Does 'perform' it mean 'run'?

If the code contained is a valid java code (including imports, full class def etc), then you can use [java compiler API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).

Once you compile it, running it is easy, since you can either [invoke java process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) with the generated class or load the generated class dynamically, and run the method using reflection.

Comment: When I execute it, would I be executing it as a .class file or a .jar?